# Display raw image as video on winform (over 30fps)

Tags: c#, image, winforms, camera, picturebox

I receive 30 raw images per second via USB. (real time camera iamge / but not webcam)

```
// raw image is Format32bppPArgb Bitmap

while ( true ) // Recevie Image loop Using Task
{
    ...
    picturebox1.Image = raw_image;
    // panel1.BackgroundImage = raw_image; // or using panel to display
    ...
}
```

**I updated the image to make it look like an Video.**
When the image is 15fps, it's the program working properly.
**But 30fps, GUI is broken.**
The image area is refreshed smoothly and well.
However, other components will not be updated if there is a change, causing problems.
(such as radiobutton, panel, title bar, etc..)
This seems to occur noticeably when the area of drawing the image is widened.

As a result of referring to other articles in stackoverflow,
I was able to check some related information, but I couldn't solve it clearly using Winform.
it seems that fast redrawing in this way is difficult through winform.
(I don't know if I got it right.)

Are there any good ways or keywords to solve this problem?
Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default bitmap resizing was thought to be heavy.
'zoom mode' has been changed to 'none'.
The image was resized to fit the panel size before making it into a bitmap.
(this case, i use opencvsharp resize / image.ToBitmap() )

The image was created and call invalidate().
Displayed through "Graphics.DrawImage" in the panel's "onpaint event".
Now everything is working normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It helped me when I called the `Refresh()` and `Update()` functions at any change on the surrounding controls.

```
// Label is only example, you can user any control you like
private void ChangeLabel()
{
    label1.text = "new text";
    label1.Refresh();
    label1.Update();
}
```

Maybe it would be enough to add only one of the functions.

Comment: You do know that `Control.Refresh()` is actually `Control.Invalidate();` +  `Control.Update();`. So now you're doing: `Control.Invalidate(); Control.Update(); Control.Update();`. I'd mention the blocking `while (true)` loop (in WinForms) and ask how the *frame-rate* is generated and calculated, how the Images are transferred, what is responsible for this operation etc.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your reply and interest. / in main thread Create and start Task(USB receive & Parsing(make image) Thread)., `tListen = new Task(...); tListen.Start(); / tParsing = new Task(...); tParsing.Start();` The 'while (true)' loop in the text is the structure of parsing thread and actually breaks when the usb is disconnected.The frame speed is consistently sent from a device connected via USB.When the data comes in, create an image and update the picturebox.The image is 400x400(Bayer->RGB). This is an endoscopic viewer that requires real-time control.

Comment: You have to show your code, to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (which is very important to determine the context of the operations). -- A Task is run in the ThreadPool Thread: the very small piece of code you posted cannot work as it is, since you cannot access a UI Element from a Thread other than the UI Thread directly (`picturebox1.Image = raw_image;`), you'd get a `InvalidOperationException` because you're attempting an invalid Cross-Thread access to GUI objects.

Comment: @Jimi The problem was resolved through another attempt ! . The default bitmap resizing was thought to be heavy. 'zoom mode' has been changed to 'none'. The image was resized to fit the panel size before making it into a bitmap. The image was created and call invalidate(). Displayed through "Graphics.DrawImage". in the panel's "onpaint event". Now everything is working normally. Thank you for your kind attention.